# I called getFewMaxNumbers with quantity=5 and arr=[0,0,0,0,0]. Why have I gotten array from [0,0,0,0,0]?

Tags: javascript

I called getFewMaxNumbers with quantity=5 and arr=[0,0,0,0,0]. Why function return [0,0,0,0] array. I don't understand. Help, me please!

```js
function getMaxIndexOfArr(a) {
    let index=0;
    for(let i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] !== "" && a[i] > a[index]) index=i;
    }
    return index;
}
let getFewMaxNumbers = (arr, quantity) => getFewMinOrMaxNumbers(arr, quantity, "max");
let getFewMinOrMaxNumbers = (arr, quantity, type) => {
    let indexes = [];
    for(let i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
        if(type === "min") {
            let newIndex = getMinIndexOfArr(arr);
            if(newIndex !== undefined) {
                arr[newIndex] = "";
                indexes.push(newIndex);
            }
        }
        else if(type == "max") {
            let newIndex = getMaxIndexOfArr(arr);
            
            if(newIndex !== undefined) {
                console.log('Eheeee!!', arr[newIndex])
                arr[newIndex] = "";
                indexes.push(newIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes
}
getFewMaxNumbers([0,0,0,0,0], 5);
```

Comment: What do you think it should return?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson [0,1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a a couple of problems with the `getMaxIndexOfArr` function.

1. The loop starts from `1` which means it always skips the first item.
2. `index` is initialized at 0, I'm guessing this is to fix the first problem, but when the array is full of zeros the comparator `a[i] > a[index]` is always false as `a[1]=0` and `a[0]` eventually becomes ""; `0` is not greater than `""`.

An approach that will work is:

```js
function getMaxIndexOfArr(a) {
    let index=undefined;
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] === "") continue;

        if (index === undefined) {
          index = i;
        } else if (a[i] > a[index]) {
         index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
let getFewMaxNumbers = (arr, quantity) => getFewMinOrMaxNumbers(arr, quantity, "max");
let getFewMinOrMaxNumbers = (arr, quantity, type) => {
    let indexes = [];
    for(let i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
        if(type === "min") {
            let newIndex = getMinIndexOfArr(arr);
            if(newIndex !== undefined) {
                arr[newIndex] = "";
                indexes.push(newIndex);
            }
        }
        else if(type == "max") {
            let newIndex = getMaxIndexOfArr(arr);
            if(newIndex !== undefined) {
                arr[newIndex] = "";
                indexes.push(newIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes
}
console.log(getFewMaxNumbers([0,0,0,0,0], 5));
```